# How to get the commit message in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am building an action that does a build for a project that will go to Netlify. In the action, I can pass a deploy message. In that deploy message, I want to pass in the commit message of the commit that triggered the build. I was looking at documentation but could not find if this is possible.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can get this in the `github` context for the action, as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context).

The event key will give you the webhook content, for example as defined [in the push event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#push).

```
${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
```

Note that different event types have different information available, and their information might be in a different sub-path. For example, in the `workflow_run` event, the commit message is available at:

```
${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}
```

Comment: Github Action no longer provides `github.event.head_commit.message` . Looks like they removed from the event context.

Comment: Hmm, looking at some recent commits at the end of March and earlier this month where I set the commit message in my workflow to `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}` it still includes the commit message, including body.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty Not every event has `github.event.head_commit` object.
While `push` does have it: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push
`pull_request` doesn't: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

Answer (score 50):

You can get the concrete commit message with the following command:

```bash
github.event.head_commit.message
```

Or it is possible to get the commit messages with the `git log` command if you use bash:

```bash
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%s"
```

**Update:** With regard to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#push), the payload and thus also the call of the commit message can get with the `commits` array if there is only one commit. The message can be fetched with the following line in the GitHub action:

```bash
github.event.commits[0].message
```

Answer (score 27):

There is a small difference between the two:

```
${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}
```

When the github push event contains several commits, `commit[0]` contains the **oldest** commit. I have seen this after a merge.

```
${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
```

On the other hand, the `head_commit` contains the **youngest** commit.

Answer (score 16):

The `commit-message` is available on the following keys:

- `${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}`
- `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}`

There is quite a lot of other information available on events.
For ex; the following workflow will give you all that information:

```yaml
# .github/workflows/logger.yaml
name: Event Loggger
on: push

jobs:
  log-github-event-goodies:
    name: "LOG Everything on GitHub Event"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Logging
        run: |
          echo "${{toJSON(github.event)}}"
```

Comment: I had to use different quotes to run. I used `echo '${{toJSON(github.event)}}'`

Answer (score 6):

If you trying to access from a different workflow, ex:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: Spec App
    branches: master
    types: completed // Only runs after spec is completed...
```

You have to use:

```
${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}
```

Comment: This one is very important, took me some time to get the right event name

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a pretty decent solution for pull requests, and I'll go through how I found it. I'll also post what you can do once you know the commit message. Knowledge is power!

My commit message example is: `the message #@content @login`

For starters, as others have mentioned, you might be able to grab the commit message from the event environmental variable. To check on that try:

```
steps:
  - name: Logging
    run: |
      echo "${{toJSON(github.event)}}"
```

If you see the commit message variable, then you can use it.

```
${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
```

However, if you can't get the commit message from the event variable, your next best bet is simple bash.

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
  - name: Set tags env variables.
    run: |
      # Get your last commit message, not the merge commit.
      text=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B)
```

It is essential to note the fetch depth since GitHub only checks out the head commit by default, which will be the merge commit and NOT the commit message you probably want to parse.

I'll also post my final solution with comments where I am parsing the commit message, looking for a flag, and then saving "tags" to run later in a testing command.

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
  - name: Set tags env variables.
    run: |
      # Set "checking" variable to false by default.
      echo "has_tags=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      # Get your last commit message, not the merge commit.
      text=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B)
      # Read the commit message into an array split by "#".
      readarray -d "#" -t commit_message <<< "$text"
      # Sanity check.
      echo "the tags are: ${commit_message[1]}"
      # Add tags and overwrite "checking" variable to true if there are tags.
      if [[ "${commit_message[1]}" == *"@"*  ]]; then
        echo "has_tags=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "spec_tags=${commit_message[1]}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      fi
```

Then, later you can use the variables in a step if the commit message has the flag and do something else if they don't exist.

```
  - name: Run tagged tests.
    if : ${{ env.has_tags == 'true' }}
    run: yarn cy:run --env grepTags="${{ env.spec_tags }}"

  - name: Run smoke tests.
    if : ${{ env.has_tags == 'false' }}
    run: yarn cy:run --env grepTags="@smoke"
```

I know this is a more complete answer than what was asked, but I figure after you find the commit message, you probably want to do something with it, like conditionally run different workflow steps for example.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone landed here for a quick solution. The `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}` is still working fine. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution how to get message of a last commit in Pull Request for `pull_request` event:

```yaml
---
name: 'How to get commit message'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - edited
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  get_message:
    name: 'Get commit message'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      # this permission should be set to be able use secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN
      id-token: write
      # not sure if this permission is necessary, just didn't try to remove it when testing
      contents: read
      # this permission should be set to be able get commits data by curl request
      pull-requests: read
    steps:
      - name: Get commits
        env:
          # github URL to list commits
          COMMITS_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.commits_url }}
        run: |
          if [ "${COMMITS_URL}x" != "x" ]; then
            # get commits list and pick up last one by jq
            # caution: only 100 commits will be taken by curl
            # if your PR has more than 100 commits
            # you have to set page query parameter
            # and request last page commits
            # API URL details: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-commits-on-a-pull-request
            LAST_MSG=$(curl -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" "${COMMITS_URL}?per_page=100" | jq -r .[-1].commit.message)
            # set environment variable
            echo "LAST_MSG=${LAST_MSG}" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
          else
            echo 'LAST_MSG=' >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
          fi
```

When `Get commits` step will be completed, commit message may be get from `LAST_MSG` environment variable

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Eshanel (`${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}`) is great to retrieve the full message.

For those like me who realized that head_commit.message includes both commit title and commit comments and only want commit title : I didn't find a neat attribute to retrieve it, so I built this job:

```
get-commit-title:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  outputs:
    text: ${{ steps.get_head_commit_title.outputs.title }}
  steps:
    - name: Get repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.sha }}
    - id: get_head_commit_title
      run: echo "title=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 HEAD | head -n 1)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

the output of which can be re-used in your job through `${{ needs.get-commit-title.outputs.text }}`

NB: you can use the simpler `git show -s --format=%s` instead of `git log ... | head`, but if your commit doesn't respect the standard commit syntax (empty line between title and comments), you'll end up with title + comments all together on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add this example which let you easily filter the commit message for a specific word.

```
jobs:
  build-step:
    name: "Build"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '#build') }}
    steps:
      - name: "Some Step"
        run: |
          # DO SOMETHING
```

Or if you want disable a step via a commit message tag you can use the negotiation '!'.

```
jobs:
  build-step:
    name: "Build"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if ${{ !contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '#ignore-build') }}
    steps:
      - name: "Some Step"
        run: |
          # DO SOMETHING
```