# Auto commit from GitHub actions on push using "[skip ci]" in comment also skips workflow trigger on tag release

Tags: github-actions

I have used the `[skip ci]` command as [mentioned here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs) to skip workflow runs in GitHub action, where I am doing an auto-commit after an image is built in CI aciton using PAT and this works wonderfully!

But as the commit comment contains the `[skip ci]` command and right after that if I create a new Tag release, the CI workflow is not triggered because of the `[skip ci]`.

Is there any way I can exclude the `[skip ci]` for tag push event and keep it only for one of my branches where ci action runs?

Auto commit in GitHub action:

```
on: push
jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: build and push image 
      - name: update image tag
        
      - name: Commit changes
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'abc'
          git config --global user.email 'xyz@users.noreply.github.com'
          git remote add origin https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          git config --global push.default current
          git remote set-url origin https://${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          git commit -am "build: Image tag udpated [skip ci]"
          git push
```

As you can see this action will run for all push events and the `Commit changes` step will make another commit using PAT but with `[skip ci]` in the comment so this same workflow is not triggered
again and it works.

But when I go to release a new tag with a new Release title and description, this action doesn't get triggered.

[image]

is there a way this can be avoided?

Comment: I don't think there is a native way to ignore those skip keywords. You maybe should do it the old way, for example using an if condition to check if all the commit messages contained in a generated tag contain a specific keyword (setting the result from the `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%s"` command to a variable in an output job, then using `if: contains(needs.job1.outputs.commit_messages, 'keyword')` in a second job to perform what you want (or not)).

Comment: Or use the event payload: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63619539/736079

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub actions uses a special kind of security token which identifies itself as GitHub actions. It uses that fact to prevent actions from triggering more actions, potentially causing a cascade.

To bypass this protection you'll need to use different security token such as a Personal Access Token or an OAuth app token to perform the tag push action.

You can store that token as an action secret.

> When you use the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN to perform tasks, events triggered by the GITHUB_TOKEN will not create a new workflow run. This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs. For example, if a workflow run pushes code using the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow

What you *can do* is to bail out as early as possible. To do so remove the `[skip ci]` token from the commit message and add your own, like `[do-not-build]`, anything will do, really.

Then add a `if:` condition on the job that performs the build:

```
if: ${{ contains(github.event.commits[0].message, '[do-not-build]') }}
```

It will trigger the workflow, but the immediately skip the job.

Comment: I guess my question was not clear enough, I have updated the question and hope it's clear emough. Thanks for your time @jessehouwing

Comment: Ahh clearer now! And sorry, no there's no way to trigger on any push events, including tag push, when using the skip CI comment.

Comment: You could add your own `[skip build]` comment and put a condition on the job that checks for that comment on the commit.

Comment: You can use the event payload to make the job optional. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63619539/736079

Comment: I tried that and it does work but it will only stop the workflow jobs, not the workflow itself as if conditions are not available at the workflow level. In my case, it's not possible as I don't want to run a workflow at all if it's not doing anything. If you can please update your answer with the `[skip build]` and event payload, I'll accept the answer as this seems to be the only solution for now.