# Possible to read git --push-option in Github Workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I would like to be able to pass parameters to my github action so that it can do different things.  Using the git option --push-option seems a good fit, but I do not know how to read that in the workflow.   Is it possible?

Comment: One possible solution could be to add your own custom flags e.g. `--do-something` in the commit messages and handle those in the workflow. Here's a thread on how to get the commit message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619329/github-action-get-commit-message