# Output from first job appears empty in second job in pull request GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

Inspired by answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77876572/11969696), I've tried to create my own GHA with two jobs where the second uses the output from the first.

Things seem work work fine on push, but when the workflow is executed during a pull request the output of `get_message` (i.e. `${{ needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg }}`) is empty.

I specifically need to get the last commit message and use to trigger a conditional behaviour, and to make this work on a pull request I can't use `github.event.head_commit.message` (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/28474)).

What am I doing wrong?

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - devl
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - devl


name: test

jobs:
  get_message:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      commitmsg: ${{ steps.getmsg.outputs.msg }}
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
    
      - name: Set tags env variables
        id: getmsg
        run: |
          # Get your last commit message, not the merge commit.
          msg=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B) >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "commit message: $msg"
        
  test:
    if: "!contains(needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg, '[skip-ci]')" 
    needs: get_message
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: test env var
        if: "!contains(needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg, '[skip-tests]')"
        run: |
          echo "${{ needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg }}"
          echo "not skipping tests"
          
      - name: test env var2
        if: "contains(needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg, '[skip-tests]')"
        run: |
          echo "${{ needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg }}"
          echo "skipping tests"
```

Here's the output of the "get_message" job here we see [skip-tests] is part of the message:
[image]

But the "test" job prints an empty string:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `"` around `msg=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B)` and `echo` keyword before it

Change you `yml` file like

```
name: test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - devl
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - devl

jobs:
  get_message:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      commitmsg: ${{ steps.getmsg.outputs.msg }}
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
    
      - name: Set tags env variables
        id: getmsg
        run: |
          # Get last commit message, not the merge commit.
          msg=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B)       
          echo "msg=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          echo "commit message: $msg"
        
  test:
    if: "!contains(needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg, '[skip-ci]')" 
    needs: get_message
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: test env var
        if: "!contains(needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg, '[skip-tests]')"
        run: |
          echo "${{ needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg }}"
          echo "not skipping tests"
          
      - name: test env var2
        if: "contains(needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg, '[skip-tests]')"
        run: |
          echo "${{ needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg }}"
          echo "skipping tests"
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have a question, though. Doesn't `fetch-depth: 0` need to kept as well to make sure the last (not just the merge commit) is also retrieved? see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715955/11969696

Comment: Also, I don't think the `ref` is the problem since the output shows that the commit message is retrieved appropriately on the first job. I just tested with the added `ref` and the result is the same.

Comment: @Ceres `fetch-depth` is not necessary while you only need the `HEAD`. By using `ref` you make sure were to checkout. So I think you had you workflow working fine what was you prblem?

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.
The workflow is not working as expected. 
The first job (`get_message`) seems to be fine - the output from GHA shows that the commit message is appropriately retrieved and printed. 
But in the second job (`test`) `${{ needs.get_message.outputs.commitmsg }}` is empty when it should've shown the commit message.

Comment: @Ceres Now I get what your problem is. I'll check what can I do

Comment: Much appreciated!!! I've done a minor edit on the original post in the hope it'd make the issue clearer.

Comment: @Ceres You may want to take a look at new answer

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I also (re-)tested with the way shown in the (GH manuals)[docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/] (echo "msg=$(git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=%B)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"), which wasn't working before. It does now, which suggests, that this maybe a combination of your two solutions.